# Transform sales order into Fulfillment

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitetalk

Here's the code I use to transform the sales order to fulfillment.  It doesn't seems to work.

```
var objRecord = record.transform({
            fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
            fromId: newOrder.id,
            toType: record.Type.ITEM_FULFILLMENT
        });
```

Do I have to add the following line in order to work?

```
 var rid = objRecord.save();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, as you have conjectured in your question, `record.transform` will initialise a `N/record#Record` object, and you need to call it's `save()` function to persist it in the database.

Comment: Thanks @michoel - you right! I have to add the save() line as well.  It's working fine now.